# Fetch Instagram live stream RTMP URL and Key

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, rtmp, live-streaming, instagram-graph-api

There are apps such as [yellow duck](https://yellowduck.tv/) that will fetch the RTMP URL and key for you. These can then be used with OBS, or any other streaming software. The feature I am building requires replicating what Instagram does, and extracting the RTMP details from Instagram for a user.

I have tried using Charles proxy to determine how Yellow duck works, but my skills there are limited, and have yielded no results.

I know that there are no public APIs available for this, and that this is probably a violation of their ToS.

Comment: did you find the solution or way how to do this?

Comment: This repository should help: https://github.com/0x962/instagram-api

Comment: yellow duck isn't working for me on Big Sur, so I'm looking for an alternative too...

Answer (score 0):

Public API for Instagram streaming available via Instafeed.me project and
Documentation on their API [available here](http://rtmp.stoplight.io).